# dump data from postgresql for use in phpunit with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, postgresql, phpunit

I want to dump data from my postgresql database and use it as a base data set
for phpunit (where I use sqlite in memory).

is it possible?

the closest i get is:

```
pg_dump -a -d -UmyUser myDatabase > /tmp/somedata.sql
grep INSERT /tmp/somedata.sql > /tmp/onlyinserts.sql
```

but the problem i got is that the inserts are not ordered, e.g. first i get some inserts which references to data in other tables which has not been inserted yet....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after trying around I got this hack to work, far from ideal, but works for the data set I got:

```
pg_dump -a -D -UmyUser myDatabse > /tmp/dbstuff.sql
cat /tmp/dbstuff.sql |grep -v 'SET' |grep -v 'SELECT' > t2.sql
sed 's/true/1/g' < t2.sql > tt
sed 's/false/0/g' < tt > testdb_content.sql
```

so it was actually not the ordering that was bothering it, it was keywords it didnt know (the error message was not giving that away though...)

Answer (score 0):

May be you shoule add -- inserts parameter to dump your database as insert statement , for example

pg_dump -h host_ip -U username --inserts  db_name  > db_name.txt

--About the  "inserts" parameter
  -d, --inserts            dump data as INSERT, rather than COPY, commands

Comment: -d i already have (see above), but pg_dump doesnt dump in a correct order. supposedly there should be a patch which accepts --ordered but could not find it